# Javascript: saving and restoring style state not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose we store a style as follows:

```
var  CSSobject = obj;
var  origStyle = getComputedStyle(obj);
```

...then we perform a number of operations that manipulate and change the style of the object. After we are done with the changes we finally do something like this to restore the state of the style before the changes:

```
CSSobject.style = origStyle;
```

The above technique works for Chrome and Firefox, but I notice it does not function in Edge 25.10 or Explorer. (Note: the objective was to restore an arbitrary state back to itself, and not to get back to defaults)

Is this a simple fix ? or is it a can of worms ?

PS. I am not into Jquery (not using it). Pure Javascript solutions are preferable at the moment. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this was much easier than I thought (especially in my case where I use no inline styles at all; it is all external CSS).

Anytime Javascript assigns a value via the `.style`selector it is essentially creating an internal style and assigns to it.

All I had to do is set the style to null and it is all back to reading the external CSS as if nothing happened `el.style = null` ... to make it a little more robust (in the off change that there is some minor internal style setting) I could save it as `var origInlineStyle = el.style.cssText` beforehand and then do `el.style.cssText = origInlineStyle`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making all changes inline, I would suggest store the `style` attribute instead of the entire computed style. This way it would be more efficient.

EDIT

http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/JXpdMB This works for me in IE and EDGE

```
var CSSobject = $("h1")[0];
var origStyle = window.getComputedStyle(CSSobject); //,null); passing null is optional or you can pass the pseudo element of which you want the properties of 
var switchStyle = function(to) {
  for (p in origStyle) {
    to.style[p] = origStyle[p];
  }
};
switchStyle($("span")[0])
```

Comment: Problem is that the changes might be extensive and often times several pseudo elements are affected. It is a royal pain restoring pseudo elements. My assignment above work beautifully .. except on IE though.

Comment: check my Edits @ThomasAn

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could snapshot current style on an object somethig like below code does. It's just and idea. (ref http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/03/15/animating-lists-with-css-3-transitions/)

```
    /*Snapshotting utils*/
    (function () {
        var stylesToSnapshot = ["transform", "-webkit-transform"];

        $.fn.snapshotStyles = function () {
            if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                $(this).each(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < stylesToSnapshot.length; i++)
                        this.style[stylesToSnapshot[i]] = getComputedStyle(this)[stylesToSnapshot[i]];
                });
            }
            return this;
        };

        $.fn.releaseSnapshot = function () {
            $(this).each(function () {
                this.offsetHeight; // Force position to be recomputed before transition starts
                for (var i = 0; i < stylesToSnapshot.length; i++)
                    this.style[stylesToSnapshot[i]] = "";
            });
        };
    })();

    /*example usage*/
    $(ui.item).snapshotStyles().removeClass("dragging").releaseSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to see a working page and exactly the problem you are facing. Since [getComputedStyle()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle) works in all browsers, I can only assume that your problems stem from the assignment of the computed value to the element's style.

I have to say that just assigning the style to an object does not restore the state of the object as it was, it only tries to force it. For example a CSS rule with !important can override even an inline style rule. Values in the computed style are computed from CSS and the state of the window, like width, for example. You set that in the style and your element is now frozen, unresponsive to changes in the size of the window, for example.

My suggestion is to find a harder to implement but better working solution for your real issue instead of using getComputedStyle. Using the style value would make more sense, for example.

Comment: Lets say we have an element with a border-color transition effect. At some point Javascript changes the border color and the transition effect is masked (lost precedence) ... how do we roll back the change. Assigning a border-color is still an assignment. Is there a way to UN-assign ?

Comment: If Javascript changes the style, then it sets or unsets some values in the style object. If you restore the style object (to all the elements Javascript changed the style to) you should get the exact same situation like before the Javascript change. You are not setting individual properties, you just overwrite the entire style object.

Comment: That's the question. How do you restore.overwrite the style object itself (I thought the simple assignment would do it).

Comment: And it should. With its original style object, not getComputedStyle. If it doesn't work, please create a Jsfiddle so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: ok, there is never inline styles in my page (it is all CSS external style sheet). So it seems every time Javascript uses the .style selector it assigning values to a makeshift style element that it appends inline. I guess one idea would be to create a null style object and assign it to the element effectively deleting all javascript changes, thus acting as a restore mechanism ... I will try this and see if it works, or if possible.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. You set me thinking on the right track !

Answer (score 0):

What can I say, it is possible, but u can do it in a different way.

U can't store and restore styles directly by the way u are trying.

What u can do is store all the styles in the page (default styles) in a JS object one by one like this way with a little help from **[jQUery](http://jquery.com/)**-

```
var defaultStyle;
defaultStyle.background_color = [];
defaultStyle.background_color.p_classSelected = $("p.class_selected").css("background-color");
```

This example is given for only one element, **you should do it for each and every style which will be changed in run-time**.

Then you should create a function for restoring the styles from stored values in JS file like this way-

```
$("p.class_selected").css("propertyname",defaultStyle.background_color.p_classSelected);
```

This should be done every element u have changed style in run-time.

> More can be found **[here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** and **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)**.

---

### Update-

U can also store your design in **[Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** from where u will restore designs.

More can be found **[here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/)**.

---

Think u have your answer :).